# C++ Variable Value Not Passing From Header to main {}

Tags: c++, class, variables, header, program-entry-point

I'm trying to make a "grade book".

I have a header file (GradeBook.h), and a main.cpp file.

I'm having trouble getting the value of a "midtermExamGrade" value to pass given the follow parameters:

GradeBook.h file:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class GradeBook
{
 public:
 void setMidtermExamGrade(double grade)
 {
   double midterm_exam_grade = grade;
 }
 double getMidtermExamGrade()
 {
  return midterm_exam_grade;
 }
 private:

  double grade;
 } //end class GradeBook
```

Comment: Show the code where you have the problem.

Comment: Do you know what a local variable is?  Ask yourself what the lifetime of `midterm_exam_grade` is, what you would like it to be, and how you could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your private member is not being initialized correctly because your setter and getter are wrong. Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class GradeBook
{
public:
  void setMidtermExamGrade(double grade)
  {
     midterm_exam_grade = grade;  // use the private member
  }
  double getMidtermExamGrade()
  {
     return midterm_exam_grade;
  }
private:
     double midterm_exam_grade; // change here to match tha names in setter and getter
} //end class GradeBook
```